# How to take full page screenshots in original size using the Firefox console?

Tags: firefox, console, screenshot

The console tool of Firefox provides a very useful feature -- full page screenshots. To get a screenshot one just needs to open the browser's command line (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>), and execute the command `screenshot --fullpage`. (Its also possible to set the filename and some options).

Working well, but before taking the snapshot Firefox seems to resize the page (proportionally), so that its length fits to the vertical size of the visible area. The result looks like this:

[image: fullpage screenshot of the SO homepage]

This approach makes sense, but sometimes it's required to get the original page size on the screenshot.

**How to take full page screenshots in original size (width and height)?**

It would be nice to get it working as wished in the Firefox' console, but hints, how to do this another way are also welcome.

---

**EDIT**

Everything works correctly and as wished!

The image / view transformation is made by my image viewer, not by Firefox!

I will delete this question now.

Comment: Original size (width x height) is relative to the machine viewing the web page, which is rarely the same on any two machines.

Comment: It can indeed look another way on another machine and even on the same machine with different zoom level. Sure, but I take a screenshot on a concrete machine and want to get everything I see now + everything a would see using the (main) scrolls -- in the current visible size (width and height).

Comment: Well you could use "Responsive Design Mode" perhaps, which allows screenshots to be snapped in various size configurations. Other than that I'm not sure there's way to give the `screenshot` command specific dimensions (or at least it's not mentioned within the documentation). Another way to do it would be to use the native screenshot capability on the machine, then you might get more the result you seek. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-to-make-screenshots

Comment: Everything works correctly and as wished! The image / view transformation is made by my image viewer, not by Firefox! I will delete this question now.